# How to create reusable fields in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to create reusable fields that I can type in, then reuse those fields throughout the document without having to retype them.

As an example, I have a cover sheet that contains "Title", "Document ID", "Version Number", and "Published Date".  I used the MACROBUTTON trick to create a field that someone can just click on and type, but I don't see how I can re-use what is typed in other parts of the document (such as putting the Document title in the header).

I've found something called "fill-in" fields, which don't seem to be what i'm looking for, and "ASK" fields, but that creates a dialog that you have to enter the information into.

I'm trying to create a generic template for my documentation needs.

Can anyone suggest a method to do what I am looking for?

Comment: Actually for your purpose, I think excel form may as well serve you better....

Comment: @bubu - No.  This is a software design document template.  It's not a spreadsheet.

Comment: actually, in my practice most 'forms' are better designed and processed in excel than in word.. anyways

Comment: @bubu - This isn't a form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just came across this requirement myself yesterday, what a small world...

Anyway, in Word 2007 the way I got it to work was this:

1. Select the text you will want to repeat.
2. On the Ribbon, click "Insert", then select "Bookmark" in the Links box.
3. Enter a name in the bookmark name box (the name cannot include spaces) and select "Add" then close the bookmark window.
4. Go to the area where you want to insert the text and still on the Insert tab click "Cross-reference"
5. On the Reference type dropdown select "Bookmark".
6. Select your bookmark then click "Insert".

In order to update all the fields you can do a Control-A to select everything and press F9 to update all fields, but this doesn't seem to catch the items in headers or footers.  My workaround is to got to the "Office Start" icon in the top left, select Word Options at the bottom of the window that shows up then under Display check the box that says "Update fields before printing" and all the fields then seem to be updated when you do a print preview.

Comment: the CTRL+A then F9 didn't work for me in Office 2010.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand right you can do it by inserting "**Quick Parts**" into your document. It is in "Insert" menu group (word 2010). For example you can add "Document Property" into document. And when it is changed through the document properties window every instance will be changed all over the document. Also you can add "Field" from "Quick Parts" combo.

Comment: I like your approach. Can you elaborate on how to create custom quick parts? the ones that exist are pre-configured. I'd like to add my own.

Comment: @Frantumn - Greg Maxey's [mapped content controls](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html) has information on how the existing 15 "document property" quick parts function behind the scenes, and also has information on how to define your own.