# How to create user-editable fields in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Similar to the question [How to create reusable fields in Word](https://superuser.com/questions/222890/how-to-create-reusable-fields-in-word), I have a document (or template) with a cover sheet with data like document title, version number and sign-off date.

I would like that the users of this document can simply fill in the appropriate "fields" and have it update(able) in references throughout the rest of the document, including in the header and footer.

I have so far been able to achieve this with document fields, but this requires that the users know how to fill out user-defined fields in Word documents. Mostly, they just select the field and overwrite it with their own text, thus not updating the field value and removing the field from the location they edited.

I have also tried using bookmarked text, but in the same way as soon as you select the bookmark and replace the text with new text, the bookmark is also lost.

I haven't been able to use form fields because in order to enable them, you have to protect the document, which prevents the users from actually editing the document that they need to edit. If I could somehow protect the document so that ONLY the fields are protected (so that the value can be changed rather than the field overwritten) and the rest of the document can also still be edited, then this is a perfectly acceptable solution.